# How to use the images taken from user using input tag HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have used `<input type='file'>` in which the user will place any image. Then i want to use that image as the background of the page. Is it possible to do that using just HTML , CSS , JAVASCRIPT ?
Basically my idea is to create a black and white image converter, i will take the picture from user input and then i will use `filter: grayscale()` property to convert that to black and white. Please help me.. My code is as following-

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
/*Code for the image entered by user --
.image{
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: url(); (set the image taken from user input)
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}
*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Black and White Image Converter</h1>
  <label for="user-input">Attach the the image you want to convert : </label>
  <input type="file" name="user-input" id="user-input" placeholder="Attach any image.."><!--Use this image-->
  <div class="image"><!--I want to display that image as background of this div-->
</body>
</html>
```

Any help is appreciated..

Comment: If there is any error in question please specify before demoting.. So that i can improve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've got your code working:

first we load the input image `input.files[0]` into the browser (here I use `file_reader`). Then once the image loads, we set your effects, then the `style.background` of the `<div>` with `id="background"` to the url of the newly loaded image.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Black and White Image Converter</h1>
  <label for="user-input">Attach the the image you want to convert : </label>
  <input type="file" name="user-input" id="user-input" placeholder="Attach any image.." onchange="myFunction()"><!--Use this image-->

  <div class="image" id="background"/><!--I want to display that image as background of this div-->


  <script>
    function myFunction() { //runs when file input is changed
      var input = document.getElementById("user-input");
      var file_reader;
      if (input.files && input.files[0]) {  //only if there is one file in the input
        file_reader = new FileReader();
        file_reader.onload = function(e) {
          document.getElementById("background").style = "position: relative; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%,-50%); width: 400px; height: 400px;filter: grayscale(100%);"
          document.getElementById("background").style.backgroundImage = "url('"+ e.target.result +"')";
          console.log(e.target.src);
        }
        file_reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function changeImage(input) {
  var file_reader;
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    file_reader = new FileReader();
    file_reader.onload = function(e) {
      document.getElementById("image").setAttribute('src', e.target.result);
    }

    file_reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}

<input type="file" name="user-input" id="user-input" placeholder="Attach any image.." onchange="changeImage()" /><!--Use this image-->
<img id="image" />
```

Try this it may help!

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<input type="file" name="user-input" id="user-input" placeholder="Attach any image..">
<button onclick="conversionFunction()">Convert to Black & White</button>
<div class="image" id="bgImg">
```

CSS

```
.image{
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  background-size: contain;
  filter: grayscale();
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

JavaScript

```
var btn = document.querySelector("#user-input");
function conversionFunction(){
var file_reader;
  if (btn.files && btn.files[0]) {
    file_reader = new FileReader();
    file_reader.onload = function(e) {
        document.querySelector("#bgImg").style.backgroundImage=`url(${e.target.result})`;
    }

    file_reader.readAsDataURL(btn.files[0]);
  }
}
```

You can also see the working at following link https://jsfiddle.net/db0w9vfj/12/

I hope this will resolve your question.